# Как написать вторую часть условий?

Tags: mysql

Вопрос возник  по одному запросу. Вывести имена клиентов, купивших товар. Если товар был закуплен только у одного клиента с id=2.

```
клиенты( id_клиента, имя клиента);
продажа(id_продажи, id_клиента);
журнал продаж (id_продажи, количество);
закупка(id_закупки, id_поставщика);
журнал закупки( id_закупки, id_товара); 
поставщик(id_поставщика)
товары(id_товара);`

select name from клиенты
where id_клиента in
 (select id_клиента from продажа
  where id_продажи in
   (select id_продажи from продажа));
```

Как написать вторую часть условий?

Comment: @aaaaa1aaaaa, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Comment: 1. select id_продажи from продажа - вернет все id_продажи 
 2. select id_клиента from продажа - вернет все id_клиента 
 3. where id_продажи in (select id_продажи from продажа)); - в которых id_продажи включают id_продажи 
короче, нечего не понятно, что у тебя таблици что у тебя столбци? какая вторая часть? where  id_клиента = 2 ?? in - сложная штука для больших выборок

Comment: Почему не просто Продажа(ИД_продажи, ИД_клиента, количество)? Вместо  

    продажа(id_продажи, id_клиента);
    журнал продаж(id_продажи, количество); 
Ведь у Вас на каждую продажу создается две записи в разных таблицах, если я верно понял.

Comment: Это скорее всего шапка документа и строки документа. Но работать все равно лучше с регистром, а не с документами. 1С рулит ))

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct клиенты.id_клиента, клиенты.имя
from клиенты
join продажа on клиенты.id_клиента = продажа.id_клиента
join журнал_продаж on продажа.id_продажи = журнал_продаж.id_продажи
join журнал_закупок on журнал_продаж.id_товара = журнал_закупок.id_товара
join закупка on закупка.id_закупки = журнал_закупок.id_закупки
where
журнал_закупок.id_поставщика = 2
```

В структуре лишние таблицы. Правильнее было бы объединить "продажа" и "журнал продаж" в одну таблицу (id_продажи, id_клиента, id_товара, количество). Аналогично "закупка" и "журнал закупок"...
Тогда запрос будет выглядеть так:

```
select distinct клиенты.id_клиента, клиенты.имя
from клиенты
join журнал_продаж on клиенты.id_клиента = журнал_продаж.id_клиента
join журнал_закупок on журнал_продаж.id_товара = журнал_продаж.id_товара
where
журнал_закупок.id_поставщика = 2
```

Comment: это если товар закупается только у одного поставщика. если один товар поставляют несколько поставщиков. будет чуть сложнее...